# Why does error message from another method occur?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class backup {
public static int t1;
public static int t2;
public static int x;
public static int y1;
public static int m1;
public static int d1;
public static int y2;
public static int m2;
public static int d2;

public static void date1() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter the first date ");
            System.out.println("Please enter the year: ");
            y1 = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Please enter the month: ");
            m1 = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Please enter the day: ");
            d1 = scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) 
        {
            scanner.nextLine();
            System.err.println("You must enter intergers. Please try again. "); }
        }
public static void caldate1() {
    int j = 693502;
    if (t1 > j) {

        if (m1 == 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 10 + 12) {
            t1 = ((365 * y1) + d1 + 31);
        } else if (m1 == 2) {
            t1 = ((365 * y1) + d1 + 28);
        } else if (m1 == 4 + 6 + 9 + 11)
            ;
        {
            t1 = ((365 * y1) + d1 + 30);
        }
        }
    else {
        System.err.printf("Error. Please enter a date after Jan 1st 1900.\n");
        }
        }
public static void main(String[] args) {

date1();
caldate1();
}
}
```

The second error appears when I cause an error in the first method. Does anyone know what can cause this? Or what I am doing wrong? It should catch errors if user enters anything other than a integer. Also does anyone know how I can set a loop to each of the methods when the error comes into effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly:

`m1 == 4 + 6 + 9 + 11` is equal to `m1 == 30`. I think you meant `m1 == 4 || m1 == 6 || m1 == 9 || m1 == 11`

Secondly:

This line `if (t1 > j)` never be true, because you never set `t1`, so it'S zero and zero can't be bigger than 693502.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, `caldate1` will always return the error case.  `int`s are initialized to 0 unless otherwise specified, so your condition of `if (t1 > j)` will always boil down to `if (0 > 693502)`, which will never be true, therefore always resulting in the error case.  `t1` is only set if that condition holds true (which it won't).

The errors from `date1` will probably not show as expected, since the `scanner.nextLine()` statement will wait for user input, before continuing execution.

Answer (score 2):

You are testing the value of t1 before you have assigned a value to it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed while reformatting your code is that you have a semicolon at the end of your last `if else` compound statement, followed by an isolated block that assigns a value to t1. I suspect you want the `t1` assignment to only occur when the `else if` condition is satisfied.

This is why it is a good idea to pay careful attention to your code style. Little things like this jump out at you when you do.